# Showing UIPickerView when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

For my app I’m implementing in-app settings using tableView with Dynamic prototype cells. Inside cell I’m showing main title and sub title. What I would like to achieve is when user clicks on one of the cells (that represents specific settings) the pickerView will slide from the bottom of the screen showing the options that user can pick. I’ve seen few tutorials where this pickerView is presented inside a cell as it is e.g. in iOS calendar app but I don’t need that – all will be fine if it will slide from the bottom actually in a same way as it is when you are having pickerView as inputView for your text field (e.g. textField.inputView = pickerView) and click to the text field. I appreciate any help you can provide guys! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can create a custom view xib in which you can have pickerView,when user click on cell just show the custom view with animation.

viewPicker = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);

For the animation from bottom to top add below:

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     viewPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
[self.view addSubview:viewPicker];


For removing the view

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
    viewPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (finished)
                                 [viewPicker removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
```

Comment: Hi Optimus, thanks for quick reply! Good stuff I'll definitely try that. Do I have to have all screens in the xib file? I guess I can have my classic Storyboard and just place pickerView into xib file. However I've tried to connect the picker to the controller (for the tableView in the storyboard ) using outlet and I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: Yeah you can use the xib file in all viewControllers ..just create one xib file and load xib file eg. 
UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyRootView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Ok Cool - I'll give it a shot and let you know how it went. It's all new to me so it will take me some time till I'll make this working I guess . Thanks a lot for your help!